# How to control when BIDS opens a package in the editor when debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis, bids

I have a solution in Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS), that consists of multiple projects and multiple packages. There is one 'main' package which will execute several other packages in sequence. When running the solution in debug mode, BIDS opens most of the packages it executes in the editor, but not every package.

What is the logic behind this, and how can I control which package gets loaded in the editor and which does not?

Answer (score 0):

It will load the packages that were open last time you closed the solution

EDIT:

maybe you have pkg1 open and when you press F5, you have pkg2 configured as startObjectID.
Right click your solution and click properties:

[image]

Comment: No, that's not it. BIDS will open the packages that were open last time when you start BIDS itself, sure, but that's not what I mean. I mean when pressing F5 and running the solution, BIDS will sometimes open a package (and display the tasks with yellow, green or red), and sometimes it will execute the packages without opening them.

Comment: It's not your EDIT answer either: the active package is set as the startup package. In most cases, I just run our 'main' package, which executes several other packages in sequence. Some of those will be opened right before they are executed, others are executed without being opened...